# In WebStorm, after Ctrl-Alt-L (reformatting) if statements become single line

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I like my `if` statements as:

```
if (true)
   console.log(1);
```

but upon <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> (reformatting) WebStorm will change it to a single line:

```
if (true) console.log(1);
```

Any ideas how to disable that for TypeScript files?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: [image]

you need to keep line breaks...